# JQGrid DynamicLink doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to add a clickable text to a column in JQGrid, hence I added dynamicLink formatter to the column, the text disappears once I use this formatter attribute. When using Link attribute, the column's data is visible. Initially i had not added the dynamicLink.js jqgrid plugin. But even after adding the dependency the issue is not getting resolved. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js" ></script>

    jq(function() {
        jq("#grid").jqGrid(
                {
                    url : '/application/getList',
                    datatype : 'json',
                    mtype : 'GET',
                    colNames : [ 'Column1',  'Column3' ],
                    colModel : [ {
                        name : 'Column1',
                        index : 'Column1',
                        width : 49,
                        sortable : true,
                        sorttype : 'int'
                    },  {
                        name : 'Column3',
                        index : 'Column3',
                        width : 49,
                        sortable : false,
                        search : false,
                        formatter: 'dynamicLink',
                           formatoptions: {
                               url: function (cellValue, rowId, rowData) {                    
                                 return 'application/disable'  + '?' + $.param({column1: rowData.column1});

                               }
                           }
                    } ],
                    postData : {},
                    rowNum : 10,
                    rowList : [ 5, 10, 15, 20 ],
                    height : 200,
                    autowidth : true,
                    rownumbers : false,
                    pager : '#pager',
                    sortname : 'id',
                    caption : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    viewrecords : true,
                    ignoreCase : true,
                    sortorder : "asc",
                    emptyrecords : "Empty records",
                    loadonce : true,
                    loadComplete : function() {
                    },
                    jsonReader : {
                        total : "total",
                        page : "page",
                        records : "records",
                        root : "XXXXXX",
                        repeatitems : false,
                        cell : "cell",
                        id : "id"
                    }
                });
        jq("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
            edit : false,
            add : false,
            del : false,
            search : true
        }, {}, {}, {}, {
            sopt : [ 'cn', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'eq', 'bw', 'ew' ],
            closeOnEscape : true,
            multipleSearch : false,
            closeAfterSearch : true
        });

        jq("#btnFilter").click(function() {
            jq("#grid").jqGrid('searchGrid', {
                multipleSearch : false,
                sopt : [ 'cn', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'eq', 'bw', 'ew' ]
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Once I added the dynamicLink.js I got a error in the browser console saying,  $.fn.fmatter cannot be resolved, as dynamicLink function definition uses $.fn.fmatter.

Am I missing any other dependency or any version mismatches causing the issue?

**EDIT 1 :**

***Updating the question***

The Column1's cellValue that is passed from the url is a boolean value, hence the

> if ($.fmatter.isString(cellValue) || $.fmatter.isNumber(cellValue))

in jqgrid.dynamicLink.js failed to pass and only a &nbsp value was returned from the function.

I am using this code with Spring MVC that works with a couple of jars for handling the json interchanges and jpa-hibernate.

I should have posted the server side code with the question, that would have made the mistake obvious.

Now, I would like to know what needs to be done for handling boolean columns with dynamicLink.

Comment: If you include `jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js` file it defines `$.fn.fmatter.dynamicLink` function. `$.fn.fmatter` will be defined by jqGrid. Look in [the part](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jquery.fmatter.js) of the source code and search for `$.fn.fmatter`. You will see that `$.fn.fmatter` are defined in jqGrid and all standard formatters are methods of `$.fn.fmatter`. Could you provide a demo which reproduces the problem?

Comment: It's no problem. Do you've found the reason of the problem? If you didn't then could you provide the demo which demonstrates the problem? I suppose that the reason is in the JavaScript files which you included and in there order.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg , I am a newbie with javascript, thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I just seen that you have updated the text of your question. It seems that you need apply `dynamicLink` formatter on the column with *boolean* input data. In the case you can just modify the code of `dynamicLink` formatter which you use. You can for example remove `$.fmatter.isString(cellValue) || $.fmatter.isNumber(cellValue)` condition and use `String(cellValue) || '&nbsp;'` in [the line](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js#L59).

Comment: @Oleg , help me understand why boolean values have not been checked for in dynamicLink.js